# css 9 images and expand one to size of 4 without going outside screen

Tags: javascript, css, image

Hi i have been going crazy trying to find a way to accomplished the following. I have 9 images, 3 in each row for a total of 3 rows. 
I need to expand each image on hover to the same size as four images without going outside width total size.

Almost the same as this jsfiddle(difference below):
http://jsfiddle.net/aseLenkx/3/

```
<div id="imageContainer">
    <div class='image red'>1</div>
    <div class='image blue'>2</div>
    <div class='image green'>3</div>
    <div class='image orange'>4</div>
    <div class='image silver'>5</div>
    <div class='image yellow'>6</div>
    <div class='image black'>7</div>
    <div class='image gold'>8</div>
    <div class='image brown'>9</div>
</div>
```

Difference being that in this example the images goes outside the container.

Expected functionality:

Hover over image 3 = image hover over div 2, 3, 5, 6.

Hover over image 9 = image hover over div 5, 6, 8, 9.

Image number 5 doesn't need a hover effect on my case.

I need to implement this with javascript without using jquery or another library.

Edited: Added new example im working on base on joshhunt feedback:
http://jsfiddle.net/rLo86uhr/3/

Comment: What about number 6? If so can you detect every third element and do something different too it? You will probably have to put `position: relative;` on to the `.image` and then animate it moving left 33% at the same time you animate the height/width.

Comment: Thanks for commenting so soon. If hover over image 6 = image hover over div 5, 6, 8, 9.

Comment: Did the rest of the comment make sense? Can you try setting up an example in pure javascript? Actually you might even be able to do it in pure css.

Comment: I didnt understand what you were trying to say about animate left how can i do that with javascript. I need to do it with javascript. :( i will try to do an example in pure javascript on jsfiddle.

Comment: joshhunt i edited my question with new jsfiddle thanks for providing feedback. You see the images push the others around...

Comment: If you are doing it like the other example you provided then you will need to clone the image being hovered and then set the clone to `position: absolute;` and then set `top` and `left` to its current top, left position in relation to the parent container. Alternatively you could lay it out differently with css so that it is already position absolutely.